# Facebook Pixel problem with Woocommerce and WP-Rocket cache

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, browser-cache, facebook-pixel

I've got a E-commerce website using Wordpress with Woocommerce. The client has asked for us to include Facebook Pixel tracking. I have installed the official Facebook Pixel Woocommerce plugin and set it up. But when checking to see if it is working with the facebook pixel chrome extension. I get the following error on every page except for the checkout:

"We detected event code but the pixel has not activated for this event, so no information was sent to Facebook."

After a bit of investigation it seems to be the cache that is creating this error. I'm using wp-rocket for caching, when I deactivate the cache it seems to be working fine everywhere. But this isn't exactly an ideal solution.

I would really need it to work with the cache. But I can't seem to find anything online about this problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

The live site can be found here: https://maradji.com/

Answer (score 0):

WP Rocket provides an Add-on (free) for the Facebook Pixel. It should work, if you used the standard plugins for the Pixel (or the ones they expect).

[Facebook Pixel Add-On](https://docs.wp-rocket.me/article/1117-facebook-pixel-add-on)

Comment: Hi thanks. I have tried that it, unfortunately it doesn't seem to make any difference :/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, this happened with wp rocket last update. Go to settings and deactivate the Combine Javascript and differed loading Javascript options. Its a shame but im sure they will fixe it in the next update.

Comment: Still no luck, but i'm not running the latest version. I'll try updating everything and see how that goes. Good to know i'm not the only one having this problem.